# pg_upgrade ERROR: could not find function "postgis_sfcgal_version" in file "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/13/lib/postgis-3.dll"

Tags: postgis, postgresql, postgis-3.0, postgresql-13

I'm trying to `pg_upgrade` folder `data` from v12 to v13

```
"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\bin\pg_upgrade.exe" --old-bindir "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin" --new-bindir "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\bin" --old-datadir "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\data" --new-datadir "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\data" -U postgres
```

I got an error `could not find function "postgis_sfcgal_version"`

```
command: "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/13/bin/pg_restore" --port 50432 --username postgres --create --exit-on-error --verbose --dbname template1 "pg_upgrade_dump_39224.custom" >> "pg_upgrade_dump_39224.log" 2>&1
...
pg_restore: creating COMMENT "public.FUNCTION "postgis_proj_version"()"
pg_restore: creating FUNCTION "public.postgis_scripts_build_date()"
pg_restore: creating COMMENT "public.FUNCTION "postgis_scripts_build_date"()"
pg_restore: creating FUNCTION "public.postgis_scripts_installed()"
pg_restore: creating COMMENT "public.FUNCTION "postgis_scripts_installed"()"
pg_restore: creating FUNCTION "public.postgis_scripts_released()"
pg_restore: creating COMMENT "public.FUNCTION "postgis_scripts_released"()"
pg_restore: creating FUNCTION "public.postgis_sfcgal_noop("public"."geometry")"
pg_restore: creating FUNCTION "public.postgis_sfcgal_scripts_installed()"
pg_restore: creating FUNCTION "public.postgis_sfcgal_version()"
pg_restore: while PROCESSING TOC:
pg_restore: from TOC entry 2237; 1255 40663 FUNCTION postgis_sfcgal_version() postgres
pg_restore: error: could not execute query: ERROR:  could not find function "postgis_sfcgal_version" in file "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/13/lib/postgis-3.dll"
Command was: CREATE FUNCTION "public"."postgis_sfcgal_version"() RETURNS "text"
    LANGUAGE "c" IMMUTABLE
    AS '$libdir/postgis-3', 'postgis_sfcgal_version';

-- For binary upgrade, handle extension membership the hard way
ALTER EXTENSION "postgis_sfcgal" ADD FUNCTION "public"."postgis_sfcgal_version"();
```

I don't understand the `handle extension membership the hard way`.
Please clearify the statement.

(I've installed the latest postgis on both v12 and v13.)